# FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible Module. Uses GPL-only symbol 'sme_active'

Tags: centos7, linux-kernel

Full Error Message

```
FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module celerity16fcmp.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'sme_active'
```

CentOS 7.6 machine unable to install ATTO Fibre Channel drivers due to GPL error in kernel.

I know what needs to be done per ATTO Tech Support:

1. modify kernel to remove GPL checks
2. recompile kernel
3. run driver again

My question is how do I go about doing this? I have test VM's I can experiment with but it might take a very long time to guess it right. I've never modified and recompiled a kernel before so I'd like to learn the proper way about doing something like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a patch for this bug in the centos kernel-plus kernel.

You can install this by running.

```
# yum install yum-utils
# yum-config-manager --enable centosplus
# yum install kernel-plus kernel-plus-devel
```

Reboot into the installed kernel and you should be able to build the ATTO drivers and continue using your Fibre Channel HBA.